# Getting YAML value from a variable Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, scripting, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a YAML file with this structure

```
key1: value 1 
key2:
  - value 21
  - value 22
key3:
  - key31: value 311
    key32: value 321
    key33: value 331
```

And I need to access value 331, so I have this code:

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

 // parse the yaml 
def yaml = new Yaml().load(new FileReader("file.yaml"))
def var1 = "key3"
def var2 = "key33"

println yaml.key3.key33 // this is getting value 331
println yaml.$var1.$var2 // this is getting null
```

Is there any other way to get this value with given variables?

Note this is part of a Jenkins pipeline.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. You can simply use [readYaml](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) step to read the YAML file within the Jenkins Pipeline

```
def yaml = readYaml file: 'file.yaml'                

def var1 = "key3"
def var2 = "key33"
println yaml.key3.key33 
println yaml."$var1"."$var2"
```

As you can see above I have surrounded your dynamic variables with double quotes, which will tell Jenkins to interpolate them.

Comment: I tried that already, but the problem is not the way I parse the yaml, is the way I access to the data. I get the same result using readYaml step. I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: @RaulMartinezLopez I have already fixed your data access issue as well. Take a closer look at the Print statements. :)

Comment: Okay, I have tried that and it works.I saw the double quotes but I have previously tried it and didn't work. Thank you so much for your time :)